# React - TypeError: instance.render is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I'totally new to React, and trying to make simple toggle button that shows '0' or '1' and this number has to be state. Terminal gives me that it compiled successfully, but i'm keep getting errors on browser.

```
TypeError: instance.render is not a function
finishClassComponent
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15319
  15316 | } else {
  15317 |   {
  15318 |     setCurrentPhase('render');
> 15319 |     nextChildren = instance.render();
        | ^  15320 | 
  15321 |     if (debugRenderPhaseSideEffects || debugRenderPhaseSideEffectsForStrictMode && workInProgress.mode & StrictMode) {
  15322 |       instance.render();
```

and here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component{
  state={
    orderStatus: 0
  }

  _orderStatusChanger = () => {
    if (this.state.orderStatus === 0)
    this.setState({
      orderStatus: 1
    })
    else if (this.state.orderStatus === 1)
    this.setState({
      orderStatus: 0
    })
  }

  reder(){
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this._orderStatusChanger}>Done{this.state.orderStatus}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I don't really have an idea what you are trying to do here, but shouldn't the method `reder()` rather be called `render()`? You error complains about a line that uses this method. The error *TypeError: instance.render is not a function* probably means it cannot find the method / function, so add an **n** where it is missing.

Answer (score 10):

You have a typo, change `reder()` to `render()`.

Comment: **shame me :(**

Comment: Typo questions should be closed with that reason, not answered.